# Add blue triangle to each slide - fill not working

Tags: vba, powerpoint, shapes, fill

I add a small blue triangle to each of my visible presentation slides that dissolves in after all other animations. This is a visual cue when doing a presentation that I am at the last animation on that slide. This keeps me from hitting the remote and advancing to the next slide before I am done with the current slide. 
I tried using the following macro:

```
Sub AddTriangleShape()
    Dim osld As slide
    Dim oSh As Shape

    For Each osld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        If osld.SlideShowTransition.Hidden Then
        Else
            Set oSh = osld.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRightTriangle, 947, 529, 6, 6)

            With oSh
                .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 255)
                .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 255)

                .BlackWhiteMode = msoBlackWhiteDontShow
                .Flip (msoFlipHorizontal)
                .Name = "@END@"
                .AnimationSettings.EntryEffect = ppEffectDissolve
                .AnimationSettings.AdvanceMode = ppAdvanceOnTime
                .AnimationSettings.AdvanceTime = 0
            End With
        End If

    Next osld
End Sub
```

There are two capabilities that do not seem to be working. The solid blue fill does not appear to be working, and the animation in the animation pane shows that the triangle should be showing up automatically after the last shape animation, but the slide itself in slideshow mode shows the triangle as soon as I change to the slide. I must be doing something really simple the wrong way. Any hints?

Comment: Regarding the fill not showing, add .Fill.Visible before setting the fill color.

Comment: As usual, Steve Rindsberg gave great information to solve part of the problem. Thanks, Steve! The full solution is shown below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted above, Steve pointed out that I needed .Fill.Visible before setting the Foreground color. The animation part was a bit more tricky. Doing AnimationSettings on the shape caused all types of problems. I needed to declare an Effect and then set the effect on the osld using the TimeLine.MainSequence.AddEffect for the shape in question, using an effectid that dissolved, with trigger AfterPrevious and an Index of -1 (last). The full code is shown below. This is now working for me.
I first delete any existing @END@ triangles then add the new @END@ triangles. This allows me to add more animations and re-run the macro to put the triangle animation last.

```
Sub AddTriangleShape()
    Dim osld As slide
    Dim oSh As Shape
    Dim oEffect As Effect

    ReDim ShapesToDelete(0)
    Dim ShapeCount

    For Each osld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        If osld.SlideShowTransition.Hidden Then
        Else
            For Each oSh In osld.Shapes
                If oSh.Name Like "@END@" Then

                    ShapeCount = ShapeCount + 1
                    ReDim Preserve ShapesToDelete(0 To ShapeCount)
                    Set ShapesToDelete(ShapeCount) = oSh

                End If
            Next oSh
        End If
    Next osld

    For i = 1 To ShapeCount
        ShapesToDelete(i).Delete
    Next

    For Each osld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        If osld.SlideShowTransition.Hidden Then
        Else

            Set oSh = osld.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRightTriangle, 947, 529, 6, 6)

            With oSh
                .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 255)
                .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
                .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 255)

                .BlackWhiteMode = msoBlackWhiteDontShow
                .Flip (msoFlipHorizontal)
                .Name = "@END@"
            End With

            Set oEffect = osld.TimeLine.MainSequence.AddEffect _
                (Shape:=oSh, effectid:=msoAnimEffectDissolve, trigger:=msoAnimTriggerAfterPrevious, Index:=-1)
        End If

    Next osld
End Sub
```

Comment: WOW!  Nice work on the animation stuff, Cliff.  Most impressive.

Comment: Thanks, Steve. High compliment coming from the master!

Comment: Master?  Nah, I just play one on the internet.  Oh and btw, please don't take my non-response to the linked-in invite personally. I nearly never pay any attention to linked in ... probably ought to just delete the account.